# are there alternatives to Salesforce ANT

Tags: deployment, ant, migration-tool, continuous-integration

Today, we are using the combination of Jenkins and the Salesforce ANT migration toolkit.
The problem is that all our other projects in the company are not using ant anymore and have moved to either the combination of Jenkins + maven or cruisecontrol + nant .

Is it possible to deploy metadata to Salesforce using any of these 2 other CI setups? (Jenkins + maven, CruiseControl + Nant)

I'm also aware already of the Salesforce DX pilot but this we consider more for the longer term when it has lost it's child diseases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generically speaking, yes, you *can* use almost any modern CI along with any modern build system and any modern code versioning system. I don't have specific instructions available for you, but assuming that all of the desired systems can somehow communicate with each other, you can certainly build those type of stacks.

Jenkins + Maven should be possible through Jenkins + Jenkins Maven Plugin + Maven + MavensMate, for example, and CruiseControl + Nant should also be possible, but I'm not familiar enough with either of those tools to determine what additional dependencies you'll need.

Honestly, Jenkins + Ant is still the *easiest* way to use CI without paying someone else for the privilege (e.g. GearSet), but the platforms are certainly compatible with each other, each having various rules for how to connect with other systems. At the end of the day, it's realistic to say that if you're willing to put in the effort, you should be able to get any reasonable combination of software working together in a stack.

Comment: I guess you're right. Indeed given the fact that with most CI systems, you can probably do things like zipping, calling out to webservices etc, you could use any of them... If someone would know of some good guides, this would be great. In the meantime I found this example maven build file https://github.com/zregvart/salesforce-deploy/blob/master/pom.xml and an article on CruiseControl https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Continuous_Integration_Cruise_Control_and_Force_Com . Others are welcome!